# Append multiple link-turned-variables once per section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title is not really clear, but I'm not sure how to phrase it. I'm working on an ecommerce site with uneditable HTML, and I'm trying to add an additional links to each product that is displayed in a page that lists multiple products. I want to move ONE link per ONE product, each one unique to it's own product. I'm trying to do this via jQuery. Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" width="33%">
        <div>
            **<a href="http://www.site.com/Prodcut1.htm" class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Product 1">**
            <span itemprop='name'>
            Product 1 </span>
            </a>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <div>
                    **<b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n">$16.00</span></font></b>**
                </div>
                <img src="Shipping_Small.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="33%">
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.site.com/Product2.htm" class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Product 2">
            <span itemprop='name'>
            Product 2 </span>
            </a>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n">$9.00</span></font></b>
                </div>
                <img src="Shipping_Small.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="33%">
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.site.com/Product3.htm" class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Product 3">
            <span itemprop='name'>
            Product 3 </span>
            </a>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n">$8.00</span></font></b>
                </div>
                <img src="Shipping_Small.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is essentially displaying a row of three products' essential information. Im trying to take the link at the top of each and append it next to where the price is shown. Ive added asterisks around the two relevant lines for the first product. These asterisks are **NOT** in the code.

Here's the jQuery i've tried to accomplish this:

```
$(function() {
     $('.productnamecolor').each(function() {
          var clicky = $(this).attr('href');
          $("<a href='" + clicky + "'>click here</a>").insertAfter($(".pricecolor"));
     });
});
```

This code is inserting EVERY link on the page after EVERY products' price. I've also tried adding .first() to the end of .pricecolor, but this just adds EVERY link to ONE product. Does anyone have any insights or clarification as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target specific element. Try:

```
   $('.productnamecolor').each(function () {
        var $anchor = $('<a/>', { //construct anchor
            href:this.href,   //get href of current item
            text: "click here"});
        //now target to insert only to the pricecolor of its own
        $anchor.insertAfter($(this).closest('td').find(".pricecolor")); 
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kEdvZ/)**

when you just do `$(".pricecolor")` it inserts the same anchor to all of the `pricecolor's`

Comment: This works perfectly. One question though; how is the constructor working exactly? Specifically, how does it know how to close the <a> tag, and why is the / at the end?

Comment: @user1925805 I suggest always prefer using constructor instead of string concat to create the element. I think you can use with or without for anchor, check the bottom section of this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element